# How to send app download link to user's phone via text when he or she gives his or her phone number

Tags: laravel, app-store

I want to code on my website where my users will give number to their phone and I will send them my app download direct link like this image(from groupon)
My framework is in laravel.

[example attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7WEq.png)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I want to know the process or the code on how to implement it

Comment: ....then you should read a tutorial and the [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section of SO ;)

Comment: did read it  :) . I wanted to know the process or how to implement it. any specific name?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be SAS sites that offer SMS SDKs, such as https://www.twilio.com/sms